# Extended use case help! UML

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

In my use case diagram, there is a use case called "View Toy", where both the member and visitor can view the toy. However, the extended use case "Purchase toy" can only be done by a member. Should I have them as separate use cases?

Answer (score 1):

Simply avoid the `<<extend>>` (leave it away). When you leave it away, your use cases still make sense, don't they? Even more since it's clear now, that "View Toy" can be preformed by both actors while "Purchase Toy" can only be done by the member. The meaning of `<<extend>>` (like `<<include>>`)  is about optionality in the implementation of the system. Not about a "call" behavior.

If you happen to need the `<<extend>>` you can attach a constraint to the connector telling that it is only available to a member.

Comment: You could perhaps also have Purchase Toy include View Toy (presumably it does IRL), with Member actor tied to the former and both Guest and Member actor tied to the latter.

Comment: @BobRodes You can do that. But I guess without the `<<include>>` it would be correct too. Using the `<<include>>`  imposes some functional decomposition which is not the goal of a use case synthesis. Each use case must be complete in itself. Incl./Ext. are about optionality (like Lego parts you can put in the system to make it more convenient).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, Thomas.  First, includes aren't about optionality, right?  Extends are.  Then, if sometimes when you view an item you will buy it, and sometimes not, but you will always view an item when you buy it (I'm thinking add to cart type scenarios), doesn't it make sense to have two use cases where the buy use case includes the view?

Comment: @BobRodes View is a self-standing UC. If the Buy UC needs the precondition that you viewed it then set a post-condition `itemViewed` and use that in the Buy UC. The "functional"  i/e is a wrong use of the connector. Unfortunately OMG did not do a good job in explaining this.

Comment: It seems that you're saying that an included UC must always function in the capacity of an included UC, and not be able to stand alone in some circumstances and be included by another UC in others.  Is that correct?  If so, would you mind pointing me to the place in the spec where it is poorly explained?  You've gotten me curious.

Comment: @BobRodes I'm trying to say that the definition in Superstructures is scrap (pp. 678 in latest ptc-13-09-05). I had a good discussion with Michael Chonoles (one of the authors) and he actually confirms this but can't find that back again :-( There are quite a number of flaws in this document (as you can find explained at http://www.uml-diagrams.org). UCs are at the "border of UML" and for that reason not well defined in Superstructures.

Comment: All right then.  Yes, there are flaws in the document.  So, is what I understand you to be saying in fact what you are saying, then?  (See my last comment.)

Comment: @BobRodes No, that's not correct. A UC must be complete in all cases. If it were incomplete it would not be a UC. `I/E` are simply wrong connectors. What we figured out was that they can be used for optionality in systems. `E` is some a UC you may or may not deliver (a real option). `I` is some UC which can be delivered _later_. This semantic is a kind of ersatz. From my POV you shall not use `I/E` since it always leads to functional decomposition.